# Binario no encontrado

Tags: c, eclipse

Buenas no sé mucho de el **lenguaje C** pero estoy testeando unas clases , y tengo un fichero **makefile** , pero cuando le doy a **Build All** en el proyecto, y le doy a **Run as C application** me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé a que se debe , ya toqué lo de las Variables de Windows , lo mismo no lo estoy haciendo bien. Agradezco la ayuda , gracias.(Trabajo con **ECLIPSE**)

Comment: Puede ser que esté intentando buscar el ejecutable en una ruta equivocada. Con lo que indicas es complicado dar una respuesta más concreta.

Comment: Qué información debo aportar más?

Comment: Por ejemplo la configuración del proyecto. Mira a ver dónde está ubicado el ejecutable y después compara esa ruta con la que está usando el IDE para arrancar la aplicación

Comment: El log que genera el output sería buena idea leer...

Comment: Igual digo una tonteria muy grande, pero hasta donde recuerdo Eclipse es solo el IDE debes linkarlo al compilador que te interese... Es posible que nunca hayas compilado con ese Eclipse? Casi parece mas que no haya encontrado el compilador mas que otra cosa. Para Eclipse tienes el plugin CDT que te incorpora compilador y otras funcionalidades: https://eclipse.org/cdt/ Si quieres ver como usarlo hay una entrada en un blog bastante interesante: https://giltesa.com/2013/03/17/eclipse-c-c-2

Answer (score 2):

Si el re-build no funciona revisa la configuración de lanzamiento de tu proyecto, probablemente no tiene una definida.

`Project`->`properties`->`C/C++ General`->`Run/Debug Settings`.

Otra opción tal vez no tan correcta es eliminar el archivo .obj que creo el proyecto y reconstruyelo.